# What is the story of Rishika Vagambharni who had reached the stage of identifying herself with Devi through her Saadhana?

Tags: rig-veda, rishi, devi

While chanting Devishukta of Rigveda (10.125) in recently passed Navaratri time, I came to know about daughter of Ṛṣi Aṃbhṛṇa​, named Vāk (also known as Vāk + Aṃbhṛṇa​ = Vāgāṃbhṛṇi). It is said that she sung this sukta in the exalted state of realizing identity with Devi. Similar thing is mentioned in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/28015/277) by SwiftPushkar.

You can read Devisukta in Sanskrit from [here](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_veda/deviisuukta.html) and English translation from [here](http://www.vedarahasya.net/devisuk.htm), quoting some initial portion from there:

> Devi Sooktam: (Part of Rig Veda 10.8.125- a.k.a. - Rig Vediya Devi
> Sooktam)
>
> Introduction:
>
> This is supposed to be the Sukta that is liked most by Devi and hence,
> it is chanted by thousands of wise men everyday.
>
> **This has been writtn by a woman sage by name Vaak, who is the daughter
> of Sage Ambrunar. The Woman Sage had reached the stage of identifying
> herself with Devi through her Saadhana - she sings this Suktam in such
> exalted state**
>
> Verse I:
>
> Om ! I move along with the Rudras, Vasus, Adithas and all other Devas.
> I bear the Mithra, Varuna, Indra, Agni and the two Ashwini Devas.

I want to know the story of this Rishika Vāgāṃbhṛṇi, if description available e.g important part/event of her life or description of how she performed Sadhana. Is this story described in any of Puranas or described by Acharyas in their commentary?

Comment: Related question: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20273/who-is-vak-the-speech-in-rig-veda-10125