# Is it okay to Chant Devi Durga mantra "OM DUM DURGAYE NAMAH" to aid in sleeping?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, mantras, devi, durga, book-recommendation

Is it appropriate to chant the Durga mantra "Om Dum Durgayei Namaha" to aid in sleeping.

Comment: People usually suggest to chant the mantra "Ya Devi Sarvabhuteshu Nidra Rupena Samstitha .... "  before going to sleep..

Comment: In some case water is first energized with the above mantra and then consumed before going to bed.

Comment: 1. Devi is the deity which controls sleep as you can see from the Nidra rupena mantra .. so chanting Devi mantrs before going to bed cures insomnia.. even Shakti Mudra is practiced to cure insomnia and its a Mudra related to Devi See a related answer  here (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20284/4732)

Comment: 2. Traditional scriptural position is that one needs to chant mantras only after initiation otherwise it is an offence and the chanting also does not have any effect but some knowledgeable persons do suggest to chant mantras after accepting the deity as one's Guru mentally. See the following two answers (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20367/4732) and (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/29929/4732)

Comment: Traditionally, sleep/slumber is one of the 3 pralayas. And so Lord Shiva along with Devi name is chanted to allow one's chitta to come forward and separate itself from mind. Once you wake up, its then chitta is clouded by the mind so Lord Narayana's name is chanted as he is responsible for Dharmic living during the wakeful state.